# Picture floats above modal unless z-index isn't defined for picture

Tags: html, css

I have a modal as defined below:

```
<style>

                                        /* The Modal (background) */
                                        .modal {
                                            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
                                            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
                                            z-index: 2147483647; /* Sit on top */
                                            padding-top: 70px; /* Location of the box */
                                            left: 0;
                                            top: 0;
                                            width: 100%; /* Full width */
                                            height: 100%; /* Full height */
                                            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
                                            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
                                            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
                                        }

                                        /* Modal Content */
                                        .modal-content {
                                            background-color: #fefefe;
                                            margin: auto;
                                            padding: 20px;
                                            border: 4px solid #7FBE52;
                                            width: 80%;
                                        }
                                        .modal-content h1 {
                                             text-decoration: underline;
                                             text-decoration-color: #7FBE52;
                                        }

                                        /* The Close Button */
                                        .close {
                                            color: #aaaaaa;
                                            float: right;
                                            font-size: 28px;
                                            font-weight: bold;
                                        }

                                        .close:hover,
                                        .close:focus {
                                            color: #000;
                                            text-decoration: none;
                                            cursor: pointer;
                                        }
</style>

<div id="trainerModel10" class="modal" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span id="close" class="close">×</span>
        <div style="">

        </div>                              
    </div>
</div>
```

And then further into the page in the footer there is an image which keeps sitting above the modal. When z-index isn't set for this image at all it sits as it should behind the modal. However when the z-index is set which it needs to be it keeps floating over the top of the modal.

```
    <style>
    .et_pb_column {
        margin-right: 0!important;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        background: 0 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }


    </style>

<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_2">
    <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1032" src=".." alt=".." width="459" height="204">
</div>
```

An example page of the issue can be found here: https://educatefit.co.uk/search-trainer/personal-trainers-finchley/ click on one of the profiles "quick view" to open the modal and then scroll down so the footer picture floats up above the modal.

How come even though the z-index is set less than the modal it still floats above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#map + div {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

will fix it. To understand why, read about stacking contexts.

In short, the principle is: every element, when given a `z-index`, it creates a stacking-context for ***all its children*** at that particular `z-index` in the containing stacking context. So inside your element, you can have + infinite and - infinite on the children (in theory, there's a min and max in practice), they will all be placed at the `z-index` of their element in the parent stacking context.

So if I create two elements, one with `z-index:1` and the other with `z-index:2`, any child of 2 will be displayed above children of 1, regardless of their `z-index`. Their `z-index` only matters on their **floor**, but they are one floor below.

So, to be able to always solve `z-index` issues, you need to find the closest common parent between the elements you want to order and give the child you want on top a higher `z-index` than the child you want below.